# How to specify external dependencies include dir and lib filename with commandline arguments?

Tags: meson-build

I'm building third-party libraries on Windows with MSVC. Namely zlib and cairo.
I built zlib in debug and release and put it somewhere.

Now I want to build cairo with meson.
I want to tell meson where zlib headers and zlib library are located.
I do not want to modify meson build file of cairo.

Cairo defines zlib external dependency as follows:

```
zlib_dep = dependency('zlib',
  required: get_option('zlib'),
  fallback : ['zlib', 'zlib_dep'],
)
```

I have CMake installed and CMake is successfully found by meson.
I tried to provide CMake-style vars ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR and ZLIB_LIBRARY.
But how to set them as commandline arguments?

I had no luck with -D option:

```
meson setup -Dzlib=enabled -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=d:\zlib\include -DZLIB_LIBRARY=d:\zlib\lib\zlib1.lib --buildtype release cairo-build cairo
```

How to tell meson's dependency resolver where to find the external dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just directly finding external library:

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
zlibdep = cc.find_library('zlib1', dirs: 'd:\zlib\lib', has_headers : 'zlib.h', required: false)
if not zlibdep.found()
   <try another lib name>
```

Comment: This works when `cmake_prefix_path` points to a directory structure with `include` and `lib` subdirectories. Furthermore zlib binaries need to be named like CMake wants them to be named: e.g. `set(ZLIB_NAMES z zlib zdll zlib1 zlibstatic)`. When calling CMake one can overwrite those names. But how to overwrite in meson? Imagine that everything is non-standard here. And after zlib is found it continues with libpng and other libraries. So all libraries had to be named like CMake wants them to be named and theirs build output had to be arranged somehow like in a Unix system.

Comment: Well, don't know then, just got an idea that you could make cmake subproject using cmake meson module: https://mesonbuild.com/CMake-module.html and that subproject will be a wrapper for your zlib installation. You can place defines you want into wrapper sub-project or pass through add_cmake_defines(). I have no experience with cmake to elaborate more...

Comment: ok, just realized why not trying to find library directly ...

Comment: Your second approach works well for my own projects. But here I try to build 'cairo' and I would rather resist patching cairo sources.

Comment: The problem reduces to this: meson should forward commandline arguments when calling cmake - how to?

Comment: ok, another try :) you can play with -D${lang}_args and -D${lang}_link_args for meson setup, e.g.  -Dc_args=-Id:\zlib\include -Dc_ling_args=-Ld:\zlib\lib

Comment: @ChristophThien I wonder if you tried? or found another solution?

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not find 'zlib' dependency.

Comment: Meanwhile I believe what I want to achive is not possible with meson. So when building 'cairo' with meson then I need all dependencies named and located as meson wants.